# Exec a running process

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have a Bash script that uses `exec` at the end to spin up a running server process:

```
#! /bin/bash
.
.
.
exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

But now, instead of just `exec`-ing the command, I'd like to "warm up" the server process before `exec` squashes my calling shell program. Kind of like:

```
#! /bin/bash

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &

for index in $(seq 100); do
    curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/warm/up
done

# => How can I exec when my command is already running?
```

As I understand it, `exec` can only take a command, but not a running process PID or something.

I really don't want to leave a calling Bash shell as the parent of my `python` server in this case, to avoid any signal-handling pitfalls in the parent.

Answer (score 3):

Just background your warmup instead of your server:

```
#! /bin/bash

{
  sleep 5
  for index in $(seq 100); do
    curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/warm/up
  done
} &

exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to launch the server and disassociate it from the shell process

```
nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &
disown
```

Then you can call your warmup urls and simple let the script exit.

Comment: `nohup` resets the stdio channels so they are no longer inherited from the parent process. `disown` removes the job from the shell's job table so that, when the shell exits, the server process will be re-parented to PID 1.

Comment: All processes are reparented when their parent exits, regardless of disown.